# Sending the object in ajax call to spring controller and getting unsupported media type message

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have an ajax call like this

```
var userList = {
"active": activeUsersId,
"inactive": inactiveUsersId
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: userList,
    url: "/ewaanmapbuilder/rest/user/status",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (flag) {
        if (flag == true) {
            $("#messageContainer").text("Status Updated Successfully!");
        }
        else {
            $("#messageContainer").text("Status Updation Failed!");
        }
        $('#messageContainer').css('display', 'block');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#messageContainer').css('display', 'none'); $('.registration-container').css('margin-top', '10%') }, 3000);

    }
});
```

In this ajax call i am sending the userlist as aobject and  my spring controller is like this

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = EwaanMapBuilderConstant.UPDATE_USER_STATUS, method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public boolean updateUserStatus(@RequestBody ActiveUserList userList, HttpServletRequest request) {     
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String adminUserId = session.getAttribute(EwaanMapBuilderConstant.USER_ID).toString();
        userService.updateUserStatus(userList, adminUserId);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("update status failed" +e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

BUt my ajax call gives me "415 (Unsupported Media Type)" error. I have tried so many options but i am not getting where i am going wrong.

Comment: Did you try data: JSON.stringify(userList),

Comment: You can try with accept header in request - 'Accept': 'application/json',

Comment: @AlokPathak I have tried by adding this headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        }, But it still not working

Comment: @ArghyaC nope its not working and why should i use JSON.strinigy I don't need that

Comment: Maybe additional Property dataType : 'json' is helpful.

Comment: Try to set: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", as dataType and accept has nothing to do with the request, only tells what response message type is expected.